# Oidc-client-js getUser() from Keycloak connection after user log-in

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying with Vue 3 Application to get out Userinfo from Keycloak on Docker.

Everything works fine but I really can't understand how to be authenticated or how to use ( or take out... ) an access token and when :

```
function loginWithOID(){
        const oidcconfig = {
            authority: 'http://localhost:8080/realms/AlfrescoDBP',
            client_id: 'alfresco-client',[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7HWN.png)
            client_secret: "HDZEwcJ8JaCB9kkBIyCEy3rXetrpn3cq",
            redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8081',
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: 'openid',
        }

        const userManager = new OIDC.UserManager(oidcconfig)
        userManager.signinRedirect().catch(err => console.log('myerror',err))
                userManager.getUser().then( res => console.log(res)

            // take keycloak userInfo
```

When i refresh the page I obtain these "documents" you can see in the Img.

in the parameters i get this in the second one :

state: 66248883805f4bbaaaee5f4585775e56
session_state: 768a6227-1c3a-4cf5-a539-be2f4da0999c
code: c7bb2264-d1ca-4a8d-a0d0-375a343cc944.768a6227-1c3a-4cf5-a539-be2f4da0999c.450a4bbe-c3dc-4c3e-8c1b-02c1247520dc

But i'm not still authenticated, there is a step I miss.

I did a lot of try, but i'm new on this kind process. Can you help me on this?

Thanks a lot.

I tryied to get user info using the getUser() , but i can't get any information. My only results is "null"

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this method to complete the login, when your app reloads upon return from login:

```js
userManager.signinRedirectCallback()
```

Have a look at how a sample of mine [handles page load](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/app/app.ts#L46) and the [underlying oidc-client-js call](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L128).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gary, the problem is i lost all the data in the refresh step, even if i try to store it i lose what i need.

Comment: Data you need should be in the response URL, so you can recreate the usermanager. Maybe try running my repo and compare its code to yours - I think you'll make sone progress that way.